# How to compile 2+ different LESS styles with nodejs, express and less-middleware?

Tags: node.js, express, less

Is it possible to compile 2 or more different LESS styles to 2 or more different CSS styles with nodejs, express and less-middleware like this?

```
var less = require('less-middleware');

app.use(less({
    src: '/less',
    dest: '/css',
    pathRoot: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    compress: true
}));
```

where LESS and CSS would be

```
style-one.less -> style-one.css
style-two.less -> style-two.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed. That is what the `less-middleware` is built to do. The middleware watches the destination path looking for any requests for a `.css` file. When it finds a `.css` file it looking in the `source` directory for the matching `.less` file and uses it to generate the `.css` file.

Here is an example using the latest version of less-middleware:

```
app.use(require('less-middleware')(path.join(__dirname, 'source', 'less'), {
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  options: {
    compiler: {
      compress: true
    }
  },
  preprocess: {
    path: function(pathname, req) {
      return pathname.replace('/css/', '/');
    }
  },
  debug: true,
  force: true
}));
```

With the `debug` on you should see something like this in the console:

```
  pathname : /css/style.css
  source : /myWebsite/source/less/style.less
  destination : /myWebsite/public/css/style.css
GET /css/style.css 200 23ms - 87b
```

And if you request another `.css` file in the same directory:

```
  pathname : /css/style2.css
  source : /myWebsite/source/less/style2.less
  destination : /myWebsite/public/css/style2.css
GET /css/style2.css 200 4ms - 87b
```

You can see more [examples](https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware/wiki/Examples) on the wiki.